# Winning of game

Tags: probability

Given a game, where we pay x dollars (say 10 dollars), if we loss, we will loss 100% (we loss 10 dollars), if we win we got 37.5% (we win 3.75 dollars).
Given a strategy with 70% winning percentage. 
Is anyway we place our bid that is able to win the game?

Answer (score 0):

Omitting units, you pay $x$. You expect to receive back $(0.7)1.375x = 0.9625x < x$.

Since you expect to get back less than you pay, **no**: You should not play using the 70% strategy.